# How to get deleted users from channel (telethon)?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

In telegram when I click Subscribers it shows me about 50 last users and about 150-200 deleted users.

I tried this:

```
async for user in client.iter_participants(chat_id):
    if user.deleted:
        print(user)
```

This gives me only last 50 users and 6-8 deleted users. I need all 150-200 deleted users. How can I get them?

Comment: I guess its `await` issue as in async functions. Do you get any warnings on console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using `GetParticipantsRequest` with offset parameter somehow like this:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch

chat_id = -123456

offset = 0
while True:
    participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(
        channel=chat_id,
        filter=ChannelParticipantsSearch(''),
        offset=offset,
        limit=10000,
        hash=0
    ))

    deleted_users = []
    for user in participants:
        if user.deleted:
            deleted_users.append(user)

    if not deleted_users:
        break

    # doings with deleted_users
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `iter_participants`, but `get_participants` works in my case.

```py
channel_id = -1234567890 # TODO: add channel id
users = client.get_participants(client.get_input_entity(channel_id))
for user in users:
    if user.deleted:
        print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```py
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsKicked
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 'YOUR_API_ID'
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'
group_id = 'YOUR_GROUP_ID'  # Replace with your group/channel ID (a positive integer)

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    
    # Fetching kicked members using get_participants
    kicked_members = await client.get_participants(group_id, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked)
    for member in kicked_members:
        print(member.first_name, member.id)

    # Alternatively, iterating over kicked members using iter_participants
    async for user in client.iter_participants(group_id, filter=ChannelParticipantsKicked):
        print(user.first_name, user.id)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

In this script:

- Replace `YOUR_API_ID`, `YOUR_API_HASH`, and `YOUR_GROUP_ID` with your actual API ID, API Hash, and the group/channel ID.
- The script connects to your Telegram account and retrieves a list of users who have been kicked from the specified group or channel.
- It then prints the first name and ID of each kicked member.

**Explanation:**

- Using `get_participants()` with a Filter:

  - You can use the `get_participants()` method from the Telethon library, specifying a filter to get only the users who have been kicked from the group or channel.
  - The filter to use is `ChannelParticipantsKicked`, which needs to be imported from `telethon.tl.types`.
- Iterating Over Kicked Members: Alternatively, you can use `iter_participants()` to iterate over the list of kicked users. This method is useful if you want to process the users individually without storing them all in a variable first.
- List of Available Filters: Various filters are available for use with `get/iter_participants()`. You can choose a filter based on your specific needs.